# How to parse through a class template?

Tags: c++, parsing, templates

I have a class template that stores a value of typename T:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    void storeT(const T& input); //Sets data = input
private:
    T data;
}
```

And I want to write a function that looks through the data and deletes an occurrence of a target. So if I were to store this sentence in T: "The rain in Spain falls neatly on the plain" then I were to call this function to delete an occurrence of "Spain " then the data would now be "The rain in falls neatly on the plain." I have done this before by parsing in strings and string streams, however I have not done it with a class template before.

My problem comes from not knowing how to parse through this kind of data. I need to find some way to read through a variable of `typename T` in order to locate a word/letter/phrase and remove it.

My first idea is to do this similarly to how I would parse through a string: create a data member of the target I am searching for, in this problem it would probably be `T target` and set it equal to the value I am searching for. Then compare the target to the individual parts of the thing I am parsing through, and if it is equal, do something, in this problem remove it.

This is where my question comes up: can you parse through a class template's data member? And if so, is it similar to parsing through a string or will you need some other kind of support?

**Edit:** T is going to be an `std::string` in all the cases I am using it for.

Comment: This seems like an improper use of templates.

Comment: Unless you know a bit more about the type `T`, you simply cannot do it. As is, `T` could e.g. be a `bool`. How would you parse that or delete parts of that?

Comment: T could be anything, even a class created by someone after your class was made, you just cannot know what data to expect when using a template or how to handle it.

Comment: Agree. Realistic other options for `T` are a `std::wstring`, a `QString` or a `CString` from some random class library. If it IS known, don't make it a template. Just write `std::string data` then.

Comment: If `T` is always going to be the same type, why on earth would you make it generic? If you insist on it: Templates are a kind of static duck typing, if you will. Just treat a value of T as you would treat a value of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not work in general. All the types you ever use for `T` must provide some common interface that you can make use of for the "parsing". But generically types other than `std::string` do not provide a method equal to `std::string::find()`.

What types `T` were you going to use this for anyway?

Comment: I was going to use `std::string`

Comment: Then why do you want `Container` to work with arbitrary classes `T`? What do you need the `template` for at all?

Answer (score 0):

`std::search(begin(data), end(data), ...` will work on anything container-like. But exactly how would you remove something from a `std::array<char,40>`? It can't turn into a `std::array<char,35>`.